# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get() on null (easy photography plugin Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, compiler-errors, wordpress-theming

I have a website with an old theme no longer supported and with a photographic plugin for the portfolio. The backend of the website is a blank page if the plugin is active, when the plugin is not active, all work fine (except for the homepage because use the plugin).
I just read all the similar question but I don't have so many knowledge on php for understand what is the problem and if there is a solution or I have to change the theme.

The problem is in line 286 and this is what I see:

```
    private function get_queried_object_id() {

    $id = (int) get_queried_object_id();

    if ( ! $id ) {
        $id = (int) $this->original_query->get( 'page_id' );
    }

    return $id;
}
```

Thanks in advance!and sorry if I miss something but is my first post here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should ask your question on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ where more people may know the answer.

Comment: Thank you!I'm sorry about that and thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Recursion

- if you want to call same function side of function (recursion).
- `$this` is use to call recursion in side of class.

```
   private function get_queried_object_id() {

      $id = (int) $this->get_queried_object_id();

      if ( ! $id ) {
        $id = (int) $this->original_query->get( 'page_id' );
      }

      return $id;
    }
```

*I think this code help you!!*

Comment: if you want to call the same function in side this function you need to use **$this->**

Comment: And this is magic, 10 minutes after the question I have the solution, it's amazing!Thank a lot Uttam, you save my day!I'm sorry if I don't reply asap but of course the website go down for hosting problem -.-

Comment: @AndrewTux if your get answer than verify answer and close.